# How does temperature affect the frequency produced by a fixed vibrating string

Tags: waves, temperature, frequency, string

How does temperature affect frequency produced by a fixed vibrating string?
In the case of the sonometer experiment, the length is fixed so temperature cant really affect length. It affects the recording of the linear density. Since the string is fixed tension can't really be lessened.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: But the length of the (total) string will vary with temperature, and thus the linear density of the string will vary.

Answer (score 3):

The frequency of the first harmonic oscillation is the higher the higher the tension in the string. As temperature increases, the length of the string slightly increases. The change of linear mass density is thus negligible, but the corresponding change of tension in the string is not. The tension decreases and thus the speed of waves and frequency of oscillation decreases as well.